# What is the influence of the number of channels on the input of a CNN?

Tags: conv-neural-network, image-processing, data-preprocessing

Let's say I want to pass an RGB image through a CNN. It has three channels, each containing a 8 bit integer per pixel, ranging from 0 to 255. Let's say I know encode this three channels in only one channel, using a "24 bit integer" that ranges from 0 to 16777216 for each pixel.

What are some practical differences in processing this two inputs in the current frameworks (tf, torch, etc)?

Comment: What kind of differences are you asking about? Different how?

Comment: Are you looking for a discussion of why this is a very bad idea?

Comment: @Sycorax: training performance, how the range of values influences the operations when they are recorded as floats, how different architectures react to those inputs... It's kind of a general question from a beginner.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy: is it that bad? Why?

Comment: In your question you said that the input is an integer. When is it being cast as a float? Note that asking about differences between how specific software libraries might treat incur a performance penalty for this kind of input is not a statistical question but a software one. Your elaboration in a comment asks about architectures. Which architectures? Can you [edit] your question to elaborate on what problem you’re trying to solve and how encoding the data in this way helps you solve that problem? The [help] has more information about how to ask questions.